# By negating all propositional variables and then flipping the truth values of all propositional variables, show that $v(\phi) = v∗(\phi∗)$

Tags: proof-verification, logic, induction

> For a formula $\phi$ built up using the connectives $¬, ∧, ∨,$ let $\phi∗$ be constructed by replacing each propositional variable in $\phi$ by its negation.
>
> So if $\phi$ is the formula
>   $((q ∨ p) ∧¬p)$,
>   $\phi∗$ is
>   $((¬q ∨ ¬p)∧ ¬¬p)$.
>
> For any truth assignment $v$, let $v∗$ be the truth assignment which gives
>   each propositional variable the opposite value to that given by $v$, i.e.
>
> $v∗(p)$ = T, if $v(p)$ = F,
>
> $v∗(p)$ = F, if $v(p)$ = T,
>
> for all propositional variables $p$. Show that $v(\phi) = v∗(\phi∗)$ (to be abbreviated as 'the property'). [Hint: This is
>   really a statement about all formulas $\phi$ of a certain sort, so what is the
>   likely method of proof?]

Could anyone please check if my method of proof is the most efficient and problem free please?

Let the length of a formula be the
number of occurrences of
connectives in it.

Base case: Let the length $\phi$ be 0. This means that $\phi$ is a propositional variable. Proof by cases by exhausting possibilities of truth value.

If $v(\phi)$=T, then $v(\phi*)$=F. Then $v*(\phi*)$=T.

If $v(\phi)$=F, then $v(\phi*)$=T. Then $v*(\phi*)$=F. Hence $v(\phi) = v∗(\phi∗)$ for length = 0.

Induction hypothesis: Let the length of $\phi$ be $\le$n. Assume the property holds.

Induction step: Let the length of $\phi$ be n$+1$. Thus it must have a main connective, i.e. either $¬, ∧$, or $∨$.

But be it $\lnot\theta$, $\psi\land\theta$, or $\psi\lor\theta$, $\psi$ and $\theta$ are at length $\le$n. So the property hold for both of them.

And because $v$ and $v*$ are truth assignments, they both respect the truth table of connectives, i.e. they depend on the truth values of the part of $\phi$ where the length $\le$n - in this case $\theta$ and $\psi$. Thus the property holds at length = n+1.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  But instead of using the length of formuls, I would use structural induction over the recursive structure of formulas ... that just feels a little cleaner.

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you so much! What do you mean by structural induction? I am afraid I am quite new to idea of induction proofs

Comment: Formulas are defined recursively: variables are formulas, and with $\phi$ and $\psi$ formulas, $\neg \phi$, $\phi \land \psi$, $\phi \lor \psi$, etc. are formulas, and nothing else is a formula than what you get through this recursive process. As such, the inductive proof can follow this exact same recursive structure: show that all variables have the property in questin, and show that if $\phi$ and $\psi$ have property in question, then $\neg \phi$, $\phi \land \psi$, $\phi \lor \psi$, have the property in question as well. This clearly shows that all formulas will then have the property.